# A zero divisor which is not an element of a minimal prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Iam looking for a ring R in whiche there is a zero divisor which is not an element of a minimal prime ideal.
In rings which I have checked I couldn't find such an element...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

et $K$ be a field, and $R=K[X,Y]/(X^2, XY)$. This ring has a single minimal prime ideal, generated by the congruence class of $X$.

However, in $R$, (the class of) $X+Y$ is annihilated by $X$, yet $X+Y\notin (X)$.

Comment: +1 As an aside one might ask why this is natural. Well in a reduced ring the zero divisors **are** precisely the union of the minimal primes - so we need a non-reduced ring. But we're also looking for a zero divisor which is not nilpotent, for this would be contained in every prime ideal - so we need to look beyond the simplest options $K[X]/(X^2)$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n$.

Comment: This is linked to the question of determining whether there exist embedded prime ideals in $\operatorname{Ass}R$.